# Adding element before a div with title attribute containing content of the div using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<li class="ingredient">
<div>
<span class="amount">1 lb</span>
<span class="name">asparagus</span>
</div>
```

i want to use jQuery to get:

```
<li class="ingredient">
<img class="myImage" title="Yes!!! asparagus" src="/white2x2.gif">
<div>
<span class="amount">1 lb</span>
<span class="name">asparagus</span>
</div>
```

so far I got:

```
 $(".ingredient div").before("<class='myImage' src="/white2x2.gif' />");
```

but how do I get the title in there. Note that there is lots of these on the page and I want the title to represent the element.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your comments, this should do it for you.

```
$('.ingredient div').each(function() {
  var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
  $(this).before($('<img />').attr({class:'myimage', src:'/white2x2.gif',title:name}));
});
```

here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NmR4P/)

Comment: Thanks! I did not know .each. I now learned it from you and will be eternally grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var newDiv = $("<img />").attr('src','/white2x2.gif').attr('class','myImage').attr('title','Yes!!! asparagus');
$(".ingredient div").before(newDiv);
```

Comment: thanks! Asparagus can not be hard coded. It needs to be programatically extracted by navigating the dom to get to the html of the element with class of 'name' inside of the element with the class of ingredient

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use the text in your span as the title:

```
var name = $('.ingredient').find('.name').text();
$('.ingredient div').before($('<img />').attr('class','myImage').attr('src','/white2x2.gif').attr('title', name);
```

Comment: The challenge here is that there are many many li elements on this page, and I want to make the title for each image of each li element unique. So this has to be done in one line. Like the example code I gave. But I have been having a hard time finishing that line.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do it on a single line, see nathan gonzalez's answer that should work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `.prepend()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each($(document).find("li.igredient"), function(){
        img_title = $(this).find('.name').text();
        $(this).prepend("<img class='myImage' src='/white2x2.gif' title='" + img_title + "' />");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KHFRh

Comment: the question is about how to dynamically add a title element to each li's image.  he's already successfully adding the li.

Comment: you probably wouldn't want to use .html(), as the title attribute can't accept html.  .text() would be better.  still not quite what he's looking for though.

Comment: You are right, it can be better, so I updated to `.text()`, thx. I just read your alternative, is correct too, but I'll keep this because is another way to do the same, so if someone like...